# React-Native navigating folders

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following project structure:

- scr

  - FolderA

    - File1.js
  - FolderB

    - File2.js

---

Within File1 I want to import a function from File2, this is what I tried

```
import randomfunction from '../FolderB/File2.js';
```

I get "Unable to reach module ../FolderB/File2.js

---

**EDIT**

I came back to it an few hours later and in worked fine, not sure what the problem was :/

But thanks for your help!

Comment: try `import randomfunction from './../FolderB/File2.js';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to go to the root path then access your FolderB file.

```
import randomfunction from './scr/FolderB/File2.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Show how you export randomfunction from File2.
Maybe you should import it like this

```
import { randomfunction } from '../FolderB/File2.js';
```